# Eevee ignores alpha in depth pass

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, render-passes

I beg pardon for this question, but I can't really wrap my head around this matter, as it works flawlessly in all other apps by default but doesn't seem to work in Blender.
Here's the issue
[image]

As you can see, there's a couple of cubes and plants which are simple planes with alpha channel. 
When I try to render the depth pass or a mist pass, these plants get absolutely ignored
[image]
The geometry with a simple material is there but the objects with alpha get omitted. I suspect that it is just my stupidity but  can't find a way to add the objects with alpha to the depth pass. 
Anyone can explain this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately I stumbled upon the material setting[image]

For some reason, if you set your blend mode to "Alpha blend" - Eevee does not render the objects with this material at all. It sort of treats them as transparent for the Depth pass.